# Construct a matrix from a set of coordinates

Tags: matlab

I have a set of coordinates:

```
 x     y
65    17
66    17
67    18
68    18
24    26
25    26
26    27
27    27
34    35
35    35
```

I want to construct a *70*-by-*70* matrix `A` such that `A(67,18)` = `A(68,18)` = `A(24,26)` = ... =`A(35,35)` = `1`, otherwise `A(:,:)` = `0`.

Is there any quick way to do this?

Comment: for the next time you're asking s.th. about matlab try to write values in a form that everybody can copy into matlab and run it directly. It is easier to understand and to copy. (i.e. as I did in my answer with coords)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A=sparse(x,y,1,70,70)
```

If you don't want a sparse matrix, convert it:

```
A=full(A)
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using `sparse` as shown in [Daniel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31447747/1011724), but here is a simple `sub2ind` based alternative:

```
n = 70;
A = zeros(n);
A(sub2ind([n,n],x,y))=1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Or, you can use [linear indexing](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511):

```
A = zeros(70);
A(x+70*(y-1))=1;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
coords = ...
    [65    17;
     66    17;
     67    18;
     68    18;
     24    26;
     25    26;
     26    27;
     27    27;
     34    35;
     35    35];

 %// creating the result array
 result = zeros(70,70);

 %// loop through the entrys
 for i = 1 : size(coords,1)
     result(coords(i,1), coords(i,2)) = 1;
 end
```

---

**UPDATE**
you can solve it without an loop too:

```
coords = ...
    [65    17;
     66    17;
     67    18;
     68    18;
     24    26;
     25    26;
     26    27;
     27    27;
     34    35;
     35    35];

%// creating the result array
result = zeros(70,70);

%// splitting the coords into a `x` and a `y` vector and save them into a cell
indexes = mat2cell(coords, size(coords, 1), ones(1, size(coords, 2)));

%// setting the ones by the indexes cell
result(sub2ind(size(result), indexes{:})) = 1;
```

Comment: I think it is the simplest way to do it. Many thanks.

Comment: @nam I updated my answer with an soultion without an loop

Comment: @nam don't use a loop for this, that's not the Matlab way

Comment: @MaximilianAst you don't need to work with cell arrays here, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31448191/1011724) for an example. (also I think you made a typo using `B` instead of `indexes` in your last line?)

Comment: @MaximilianAst I wasn't saying you should remove the loop code! It's quite useful for anyone trying to learn. I think you should put it back in!

Comment: @Dan I rolled it back ^^

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way using [`accumarray`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
result = accumarray([x(:) y(:)], 1, [70 70]); %// full matrix
```

The third input argument, `[70 70]`, specifies matrix size.

---

If you prefer `sparse` result, use a sixth input argument (called `issparse` in the documentation) as follows:

```
result = accumarray([x(:) y(:)], 1, [70 70], [], 0, true); %// sparse matrix
```

---

Either of the above statements accumulates coincident values. That is, if there is a repeated coordinate you will get a value `2` at that entry. If you want to keep value `1` in those cases, change the fourth input argument:

```
result = accumarray([x(:) y(:)], 1, [70 70], @(x) 1, 0); %// force 1, full matrix
```

This could of course be combined with the `issparse` flag set to `true`:

```
result = accumarray([x(:) y(:)], 1, [70 70], @(x) 1, 0, true); %// force 1, sparse matrix
```